# inserting a new parent

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I have a sample code like this

```
  <svg id="id1"> 
    <element1>
    </element1>
    <element2>
    </element2>
    </svg>
```

How can i insert a node element g using javascript to look like this

```
     <svg id="id1"> 
       <elementadd>
        <element1>
        </element1>
        <element2>
        </element2>
       </elementadd>
     </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parent = document.getElementById('id1');
var new_el = document.createElement('elementadd');

while( parent.firstChild ) {
    new_el.appendChild(parent.firstChild);
}

parent.appendChild(new_el);
```